# How can I add some websites link to browser's favorite(bookmark) for users in domain using batch script?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-server-2003, group-policy, bash-scripting

I wanna add some website's link into all users bookmark(favorite in IE) automatically when user log in to windows using batch script or something like that?
Is there any policy in windows server 2003 to do that?
**one more thing :**
I wanna categorized websites into their group for example :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Favorites that appear in IE are actually URL files in a folder in the user profile.
So if you want to add some Favorites to users you have 3 options:

1. Create a GPO > User Settings > Preferences > Windows Settings > Folders, then add there the folder that holds all your Favorites.
2. Create a logon script that copies the Favorites folder.
3. If you have one terminal server, you could use the "All Users > Favorites" folder, which shows up on every user Favorites that logs on to that terminal.

Either way, you need to create the Favorites folder in a shared location, and create it the way you want everyone to see it.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a bookmark called "HelloWorld" that points to "http://www.google.com" (For Internet Explorer)

```
@echo off
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > CreateShortcut.vbs
echo sLinkFile = "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Favorites\HelloWorld.lnk" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.TargetPath = "http://www.google.com" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.Save >> CreateShortcut.vbs
cscript CreateShortcut.vbs
del CreateShortcut.vbs
```

Comment: should I rewrite these lines of code for each website?

Comment: I cannot say what you *should* do; however that would be one way of doing this. About how many websites are you talking about? Will you need to include additional websites as time goes on?

Comment: about 100 websites in different categories .